# WPF vertical scrollbar aligns with text and not with textbox width

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface

For an application written in C# using WPF I have the following issue:

I have a textbox with text that is being pulled from a database. The length and format of the text can vary from being a short remark, to a long text of multiple paragraphs. In some edge cases, we get text which consists of many short lines [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npMZi.png). Because space is limited vertically and horizontally, we need to define the dimensions of the textboxes to fit the UI [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npMZi.png). As you can see, in the case where the textbox has to display more than 5 lines, with the lines being very short, we get a situation where the scrollbar doesn't align with the right side of the textbox, but aligns with the text itself.

I have tried to put the textbox inside of a Scrollviewer and tried to fix the issue this way, but this resulted in the scrollbar being outside of the textbox, with the thumb of the scrollbar not showing and the dimensions of the scrollbar itself being completely off.

The final result should be a scrollbar that is always aligned to the right side of the textbox, no matter the length of the text that is being displayed.

[Examples of textboxes, top one being an edge case which comes up sometimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npMZi.png)

```
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                           Content="{StaticResource NominationInfo_OperatorRemarks}"
                           Style="{StaticResource UnderlineLabel}" />

                    <TextBox Width="500"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             MaxLines="5"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Text="{Binding OperatorRemarks, Mode=OneWay}"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    </TextBox>

                    <Label Grid.Row="2"
                           Content="{StaticResource NominationInfo_LoadingInstructions}"
                           Style="{StaticResource UnderlineLabel}" />

                    <TextBox Grid.Row="3"
                             MaxLines="5"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                             Text="{Binding OperatorInstructions, Mode=OneWay}"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             Width="500"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have confounded `HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment`.
Putting the following code to the `TextBox` should do the trick.

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
```

Comment: Adding the HorizontalContentAlignment property and setting it and HorizontalAlignment to "Stretch" solved the issue! Thank you for the help!